# My dog goes crazy barking when I return home

Tags: vocalizations

I can be gone for 30 minutes or all day (work). He goes crazy barking, whirling around, preventing me from walking into the house. If anyone saw him, they would think he is being aggressive, but he isn't. He has never bitten anyone, and I am "his person". The problem is my other dog thinks he is being aggressive, and is confused, and he barks at me now also. Oh, and if I try ignoring him, it goes on and on - longer than 5 minutes.

He only does this with me. My roommate can come in, and he doesn't bark at him at all. Interestingly, I can remember when this started. I had him about 3 months (he is a 4 year old rescue), and one day he decided I was "his". He began following me around everywhere, and this behavior started also.

BTW, I read the post "My dog gets aggressive to me when I come home", and the actions are not similar in that he doesn't ever bite. He is a very sweet natured dog, and except for this annoying behavior, he is a good dog.

Answer (score 3):

Is he neutered?  That might help calm him down some.  But you should talk to your vet and ask if there could be a medical reason fo his actions and then for a number for a respectable behaviour specialist.  He has some separation-anxiety issues it sounds like and if you can't stop soon, it will only get harder if it can be stopped at all.  There are some things you can try at first, such as "Calming music" for dogs to help the stay calm (download from your phone and put on cd), when you leave tell him you'll be right back (even if is going to be 10 hrs.) but don't make an issue of leaveing (no eye contact when you do leave), when you return, calmly say hi and if he's really excited tell him that his action is inappropriate behavior and go lay down, once hes calm, go up to hem and give him tons of loving and a small treat.  But talk to your vet before anything, make sure he is healthy. Good luck!